# Trying to diagnose NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am writing code for a course. We are meant to scan lines from a file specified by the user, search each line for one or more words specified by the user, and report how many times in the whole file (having processed line by line) these words are present. We are given three classes, and meant to write the fourth. My code is throwing a NullPointerException on line 12, and I'm not sure why. As far as I can see I have both declared and initialized the variables involved in that line. My code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class WordFreq extends Echo{
  String[] searchWordsAsStrings;
  WordCount[] searchWords;

  public WordFreq(String f, String w) throws IOException{
    super(f);
    searchWordsAsStrings = w.split(" ");
    for(int a = 0; a < searchWordsAsStrings.length; a++){
      searchWords[a] = new WordCount("");
    }
    for(int a = 0; a < searchWordsAsStrings.length; a++){
      searchWords[a].setWord(searchWordsAsStrings[a]);
    }
  }

  public void processLine(String line){
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
      for(int a = 0; a < searchWords.length; a++){
        if(searchWords[a].getWord() == st.nextToken()){
          searchWords[a].incCount();
        }
      }  
    }
  }

  public void reportFrequencies(){
    System.out.println("Word counts:");
    for(int a = 0; a < searchWords.length; a++){
      System.out.println(searchWords[a].toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at WordFreq.<init>(WordFreq.java:12)
    at FreqStudy.main(FreqStudy.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

The main class of this application is below. I have commented out the given code and provided my own, in an effort to diagnose the problem.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FreqStudy{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    /*
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter file name");
    String fileName = scan.next();
    */
    String fileName = "pg37997.txt";
    /*
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter words to search for");
    System.out.println("enter lower case, separated by spaces");
    String wordString = scan2.nextLine();
    */
    String wordString = "cow horse chicken goat pig";
    WordFreq f = new WordFreq(fileName,wordString);
    f.readLines();
    f.reportFrequencies();
  }
}
```

This application also uses the Echo and WordCount classes, provided below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Echo{
  String fileName; // external file name
  Scanner scan; // Scanner object for reading from external file

  public Echo(String f) throws IOException
  {
    fileName = f;
    scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
  }

  public void readLines(){ // reads lines, hands each to processLine
    while(scan.hasNext()){
      processLine(scan.nextLine());
    }
    scan.close();
  }

  public void processLine(String line){ // does the real processing work
    System.out.println(line);
  }
}

public class WordCount{

  private String word;
  private int count;

  public WordCount(String w){
    word = w;
    count = 0;
  }

  public String getWord(){
    return word;}

  public void setWord(String w){
    word = w;
  }

   public int getCount(){
    return count;}

  public void incCount(){count++;}

  public String toString() {
    return(word +  " --- " + count);
  }

  public boolean equals(Object other){
    WordCount i = (WordCount)other;
    return (this.word.equals(i.word));
  }
}
```

I well and truly cannot trace where the exception is coming from. I've read up on what generates it (many explanations on this site) but I cannot diagnose what in my actual code is throwing the exception.

Many thanks.

Comment: And which is line 12?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through and you'll answer your own question.

Comment: Set the size of your arrays.

Comment: Chris, line 12 is "searchWords[a] = new WordCount();" I couldn't find a way to enable line numbering.

Comment: adchilds, the problem is that I don't know what the size is. The size should be searchWordsAsStrings.length, since it depends on the number of search terms the user inputs.

Comment: Vaibhav, do you know of any good debuggers for Java? That isn't a tool our instructor has set us up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WordCount[] searchWords;` array never gets initialized.

Add a `searchWords = new WorkCount[searchWorkdsAsStrings.length];` under `searchWordsAsStrings = w.split(" ");`

**EDIT**

To answer your question from comment below, the st.nextToken() advances the token and this is what is throwing your NoSuchElementException. Instead of doing that inside your for loop, read the st.nextToken() into a variable and then do your == comparison.

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        String s = st.nextToken();
      for(int a = 0; a < searchWords.length; a++){
        if(searchWords[a].getWord().equals(s)){
          searchWords[a].incCount();
        }   
      }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much. My problem was that similar lines weren't compiling correctly, but I think (as I've read elsewhere) that not including the type on the left-hand side of the assignment helps. For some reason. This is why I wish they'd teach us Ruby instead of Java.

Comment: Curiously, I'm now getting a NoSuchElementException from line 24 even though it's within a while(st.HasMoreTokens()) condition.

Comment: Yeah, I switched the order of the loops. The problem is that I was iterating over the number of search words and THEN the number of tokens, such that with five search words, it was trying to read five times more tokens than the input file actually had. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Another quick question. I notice that if I change your .equals() method to a simple equals sign, my program returns 0 found values, whereas it works with the .equals(). I've been told the two are equivalent. Why is this?

Comment: They are not equivalent at all. equals() compares the string values whereas == is comparison object equality.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is because of an improperly initialised array!

```
WordCount[] searchWords;
```

But you never declare `searchWords = new WordCount[dimension];`

When you attempt to reference this array, you're trying to access something that doesn't exist. Because `WordCount[]` is an object in, and of, itself, it is throwing a `NullPointerException` because it does not yet reference a `WordCount[]` object.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are attempting to assign objects to the searchWords array before it is initialized (unless this is done in the super class). Make sure you initialize the array like

```
WordCount[] wordArray = new WordCount[10];
```

or

```
WordCount[] wordArray = new WordCount[]{new WordCount()};
```